# How do I copy a friend's Facebook profile picture to Google Contacts?

Tags: facebook, google-contacts

How do I copy a friend's Facebook profile picture to my Google Contact entry for my friend?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: @user219162 please accept my answer if it answered your question, by clicking on the tick underneath the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the photo. On the website, you achieve this by clicking "Options" at the bottom of the photo, then "Download".
2. Upload the photo as the contact's profile photo. On [contacts.google.com](https://contacts.google.com/), you can achieve this by going to the contact, then clicking the pencil icon (which means 'edit'), then clicking on the grey profile icon on the left. The following screenshot shows this:

[image]